# As Day Light Save has started my custom app not working?

Tags: javascript

Currently we are in USA - EST time zone

By using the below JS I'am able to determne the local time zone, we are getting our zone as EST from the below JS until last week. well.

> util.printd("HH:MM:SS Z", new Date(), true).substring(9)

But, today we are getting it as EDT!!

Pls. let me know the correct JS snippet, wherein irrespective of Day Light Saving we must get see/get as EST, I mean, in all seaons we want the JS's outcome as EST only

Pls. help us in this regard

Thank you

Comment: I am very confused as to what you are asking. Currently, we are on EDT in the eastern timezone, so what is the problem?

Comment: Well, but you *are not* in EST anymore. You're in EDT now. What do you want to use this information for exactly?

Comment: That's exactly how `Date` is supposed to work, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date): *If no arguments are provided, the constructor creates a JavaScript Date object for the current date and time according to system settings.* Your system settings are EDT.

Comment: You could probably use `.getTimezoneOffset` and compare it to what you'd expect for EST (i.e. `300`) and then subtract an hour if you are in EDT (offset is `240`).

Comment: I'm Sorry for not explaining my question in details. OK, as I said the above JS is giving me as EDT, well. But, I want a JS, which gives as EST in all seasons irrespective of DayLight Save. Its bcz of that we are passing this time zone to a back end system, wherein only EST is there, there is no EDT in that back end system. We don't care DayLight Save, in this example, we need just as EST, pls. provide me a JS Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var currentDateTime = new Date();
if (currentDateTime.getTimezoneOffset() !== 300) {
   currentDateTime = new Date(currentDateTime.getTime() - (60 * 60 * 1000));
}
```

`300` is the offset for EST. `.getTime()` will return the number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970 (Unix epoch) so we subtract one hour from that (60 minutes/hr * 60 seconds/min * 1000 ms/s) and construct a new `Date` object with the result that is now 1 hour behind the time our system is reporting.

If you wanted to make this more robust, you could actually calculate the difference between `getTimezoneOffset` and `300` and adjust accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. I just gave as an example purpose as EST/EDT, but, as we are multi-national company, we need to consider all time zones, as I said in my original question the said JS is giving me as EDT, but we need EST in all seasons irrespective of Day Light Save stuff. Pls. provide me a JS, Thank you

Comment: @user3406679: Firstly, this isn't a code writing service. Secondly, I've detailed a way you can figure out what the difference is between the time zone in a `Date` object and EST. What part of it don't you understand?